# How to prevent antd multiselect from growing in height / how to customize multiselect label?

Tags: reactjs, antd

If I set the antd `<Select/>` `maxTagTextLength` to something tiny like `4` it works, but is there a way to make it show just `2+ items` if more than one item is selected, so it always stays on one line? How do I customize the selected tag label so it just shows one label and shows something custom? I would like for these two inputs to have the same height when multiple items are selected. Ideally in the first input it would say "2 cities selected" and in the second, "2 values selected".

[image]

Comment: One line using minWidth: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/select-multiple-with-antd-gw99tl

Answer (score 1):

You can manage `maxTagCount` in component's state

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const maxTagCount = count > 1 ? 0 : 1;

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setCount(value.length);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      onChange={handleChange}
      mode="multiple"
      maxTagCount={maxTagCount}
      options={options}
    />
  );
};
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-21-4-forked-5n541y?file=/demo.js:0-614)

Answer (score 0):

`const customMaxTagPlaceholder = (omittedValues: any) => ( <div className={styles.maxTagPlaceholder} > {`+ ${omittedValues.length} ...`}

);

```
 <Select
  maxTagCount={"responsive"}
  tagRender={customTagRender}
  maxTagPlaceholder={customMaxTagPlaceholder}
```

/>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).